# How to create a pipeline to just rename columns?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My use case is quite simple. A data provider puts CSV files on Google Storage every hour. Once a day, a Transfer job picks up those files and sends to a BigQuery table. The problem is that I need to rename those fields.

The first thing that came to me was simply using a scheduled query like

```
SELECT bad_field AS good_field (...) FROM raw_table
```

and schedule that query to append the results to a nicer table. I'm not sure if that's a very clean solution because I'm just starting out with BigQuery.

I have also read about DataFlow but I have no experience with that service.

Does anybody have had this sort of scenario? How did you deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule a local cron to do this job for you and load your data with fields named whatever you want into a BigQuery table. All you have to do is to specify a schema based on which your CSV files are to be parsed, and you will be good with the naming of your columns.

Let's say your CSV file has 3 columns, and you want them to be named `X,Y,Z`. Then you can schedule this `gcloud` command to do the job for you:

```
 bq --location=US \  
 load \ 
 --replace=false \ 
 --source_format=CSV \ 
 --skip_leading_rows=1 \ 
 `yourdataset.tablename` \ 
 gs://yourbucket/date/*.csv \ 
 --schema=X:STRING,Y:FLOAT,Z:STRING
```

Please note the following:

- The `--skip_leading_rows=1` parameter (which assumes that first row is header and it just skips it).
- The `--replace=false` parameter (which doesnt let the job to overwrite, but to append to the target table.
- The `--schema` parameter, which specifies the schema as a comma-separated list of `KEY:FORMAT`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! Does it delete the exported CSVs automatically or I'd need to add another command to do that?

Comment: you have to add another command :-) : `gsutil rm -r gs://yourbucket/date/*.csv`

Comment: If it helps resolving issue, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @khan. I didn't mark because I haven't had the time to try it yet. I'll probably do that in the next couple of days :D

Comment: I ended up using an Airflow pipeline to make the conversion I needed and other transformations in the data at once. I'll mark this as answered because it really did its job! Thank you